# Minimal requirements for a portable computer for writing only?

Tags: tools

What have you found to be the least expensive portable computer that will handle Microsoft Word?  I don't need any other Office applications or the internet;  however, I do need either a USB connection or a CD drive so I can save my work and take it to a printer.

Comment: I won't answer as it wouldn't be an actual answer to the question you ask - but have you considered a word processor? Might be cheaper.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about writing. It is about what computer to use.

Comment: This seems to me to be a useful question, since "minimal writing computer" would be a useful question to many writers. But I'm open to opinions if others think this is off-topic.

Comment: You could go to the Microsoft website, choose which version of Word you want, look at the minimum hardware specifications and then search for a machine that fitted that. However, in my experience the minimum specified might work if you want to wait forever for something to happen. You need the highest specification hardware you can afford, particularly if you expect to use it for more than a month or two after buying it.

Comment: Actually, if you don't go with newest Word, you could get paid for removing a 486 or Pentium1 running Win95 and MS Word from someone's garage... or just hunt down one on a freecycling site.

Comment: Are you saying that you want Microsoft Word just because you know that's a common word processor or are you specifically wanting Word?  Libre Office/Open Office are free and are compatible with Microsoft Word documents.  I write on an ancient Dell Latitude D430 with Linux Mint loaded on it.  I use Libre Office when writing and Kabikaboo to keep myself organized.

Comment: Voting to close also. The title and body are asking two different questions, and the correct answer to 'least expensive' would require a vast amount of research, and would produce a different answer every day. Can you rephrase the question to highlight a particular problem preventing a writer from going to a computer store and just selecting the cheapest model?

Comment: Have you considered a Chromebook?  That's what I use exclusively for writing.  They are cheap and perfect for writing; you would need to use Google Drive instead of Word (Drive is much better IMO).  You can edit offline without internet and sync when you get back online.  You can also write from any computer/location without worrying about your documents being saved on a specific computer and having to transfer them.  I've owned the Samsung Chromebook 1 and 2 and I plan to purchase number 3 when it comes out later this year.

Comment: If you're down for trying Google Drive, Chromebooks have so many pros for writing.  Portable, cheap and internet-based.

Comment: @mwo Hmm, the question should be closed because it would take a lot of research to answer? I don't see how that's a valid criterion. What, we only accept easy questions? If you're not prepared to do the research to answer the question, then don't answer. Don't close the question.

Comment: @Jay, a vast amount of research which woud be invalidated almost immediately by changing prices. https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

Answer (score 1):

The minimum writing computer today is an iPad mini 2 with a Bluetooth keyboard, which you can get for about $300 total. It is basically a digital typewriter.

Key advantages over a traditional PC:

- it is mobile and has 10 hour battery, so you can take it everywhere with you so that you can write whenever and wherever inspiration strikes
- you can choose from literally thousands of Bluetooth keyboards, either generic ones or ones that are made specifically for iPad, and that enables you to choose one that really suits your taste, as opposed to just using whatever keyboard is built-into a cheap notebook or came with a cheap desktop
- there are writing apps for iPad that are totally focused on writing, and are much better for a writer than Microsoft Word, with less distractions, auto-save, auto-backup, beautiful text rendering, and they cost $0 to $10 each — but if you specifically need Microsoft Word, it runs on iPad also
- there are great note-taking and outlining tools, again that are only $0 to $10
- there are great native blogging tools, so that you can very easily manage a blog to go with your writing, and these are typically free
- your writing apps run full screen by default (although you can bring a second app out from the side) so that you are really focused on your writing, like with a typewriter — the default style is like Kerouac’s typewriter with teletype paper in it: a giant endless page that you can type into without distraction
- iPad backs itself up to the cloud, so you don’t need to work with disks or USB keys to do that — although there are USB keys with both USB and Lightning that work with iPad
- there are apps for sending print jobs directly to printers over the Internet — for example there is one that you can use to send a print job to a FedEx Office and then you go to the FedEx Office location and put a code into a photocopier and your print job comes out
- you spend less time working with the computer, troubleshooting it, using USB keys, backing it up, and so on, and therefore you get more time and focus for your writing.

Today, ideally you don’t go to a computer or lug a computer around, and you don’t use sneakernet with USB keys — you just have writing tools in a backpack or briefcase or purse that you can use at any time and which can send print jobs over the Internet and back themselves up over the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

As Tave says in a comment, to get an authoritative answer you could go to the Microsoft website, check the system requirements for MS Word, and then go to any website that sells computers and look for something meeting those requirements.

In practice, with the current state of technology, MS Word is a pretty light load for a modern computer. If that's all you plan to run on it, I think almost any current generation computer would do the trick. I'd suggest you consider what size keyboard and display you want.

I think you'd have little trouble finding a low-end laptop adequate to the job for under $300.